# Print array values one after another

Tags: powershell, for-loop, powershell-2.0

I have two arrays with different values as follows

```
$DevID={101,102,103,104}
$ProdID={201,202,203,204}
```

And I want the output to be printed as the first `DevID` followed by `ProdID`,as shown below,

```
101
201

102
202

103
203

104
204
```

How can I get the above shown output in PowerShell?

Comment: Please make some effort to implement it in PowerShell, and then state the specific problem you have with your implementation, we're here to help you, not to solve the problem for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the curly bracket you defined two scriptblocks. You instead want to use `@(....)`:

```
$DevID=@(101,102,103,104)
$ProdID=@(201,202,203,204)
```

Now to get your desired output you could use a for-loop and access the lists by the current index:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $DevID.Count; $i++)
{
    $DevID[$i]
    $ProdID[$i]
}
```

**Output:**

```
101
201
102
202
103
203
104
204
```